# Echo texte from function with include in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following files structure (and need to keep it):

**index.php page:**

```
<?= showText(); ?>
```

**lang.php page:**

```
<?
  $lang___1 = "Text 1";
  $lang___2 = "Text 2";
  $lang___3 = "Text 3";
  $lang___4 = "Text 4";
?>
```

**datas.php:**

```
<?
$array = array(
    '0'    => $lang___1,
    '1800' => $lang___2,
    '3600' => $lang___3,
    '7200' => $lang___4
);
return $array;
?>
```

**function.php page:**

```
<?
function showText() {
  $itemsArray = include 'datas.php';
  foreach($itemsArray as $key=>$val){
    $html .= $val;
  }
  return $html;
}
?>
```

---

My problem is nothing is echoed actually.

I try several things like `$$` but nothing.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you including `lang.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Only bits of your code are being included

First fix `datas.php` like this

```
<?php
$array = array(
    '0'    => $lang___1,
    '1800' => $lang___2,
    '3600' => $lang___3,
    '7200' => $lang___4
);
// this is not a function so return is not required
// $array will be available in the scope of the file that includes it
//return $array;
?>
```

And fix `function.php`

```
<?php
function showText($itemsArray) {
  foreach($itemsArray as $key=>$val){
    $html .= $val;
  }
  return $html;
}
?>
```

And change`index.php`

```
<?php
require 'lang.php';
require 'datas.php';
require 'function.php';

<?= showText($array); ?>
```

Comment: though, the way he returned the `$array` and assigned it to `$itemsArray` would have worked, wouldn't it? Example #5 in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: @Jeff **NO** Returned `$array` from what. That was not a function it was simple inline code. So the `return $array;` would actually have terminated the script, much like an `exit` would

Comment: The array from `datas.php`. According to the docs it is possible the way he did it. (example #5 of manual about `include`)

Comment: @Jeff Yes you are right, I had missed that it was being assigned to a variable